# How to compute $\lim_{s \to 1} (s-1) \frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} $ ?

Tags: limits, analytic-number-theory

I wish to verify the conditions of a certain theorem to prove that the integral $$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\psi(x) - x}{x^2} dx $$ converges. (Where $\psi(x) = \sum_{n\leq x}  \Lambda (n) $, and $\Lambda$ is the von Mangoldt funtion.) To do this, I need to compute 
$$\lim_{s \to 1} (s-1) \frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} ,$$ but I am not entirely sure how to do so. I guess one could use the functional equation for the zeta function, but I suppose I'm missing something. Could you please help me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Riemann zeta function has a simple pole at $s = 1$ with the Laurent expansion

$$
   \zeta(s) = \frac 1{s-1} + O(1) 
$$

It follows that 
$$
   \zeta'(s) = -\frac 1{(s-1)^2} + O(1) 
$$
for $s \to 1$ and therefore
$$
\lim_{s \to 1} (s-1) \frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} = -1 \quad .
$$

Generally, if $f$ is meromorphic in a neighborhood of $z_0$ and has a zero
of order $k$ (or a pole of order $-k$) at $z_0$, then

$$
\lim_{z \to z_0} (z-z_0) \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} = k \quad .
$$